# Can an electron and a positron annihilate to form a Z_0 boson?

Tags: particle-physics

I guess that, since the Z boson is more massive than both the electrons, they need to go pretty fast (so that their kinetic energy is large enough),
but **is annihilation a property of the electromagnetic force only**?
Can the weak force also cause annihilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [LEP collider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Electron%E2%80%93Positron_Collider) collided electrons and positrons to make Z bosons.

Comment: so is this due to the weak force or to the electromagnetic force?

Comment: Don't make us do your homework for you ;)

Comment: It's not homework actually, I did't put the tag.
I am not asking you to do any calculation.
I am just asking whether annihilation is only mediated by the electromagnetic force or whether it can also happen via the weak force

Comment: @Harold: In the SM there exists a weak vertex, $e^- e ^+Z$, so you can create $Z$ bosons "directly" using the weak interaction. You can have some intermediate electromagnetic interactions but they will be higher order processes.